# How to specify there be at least one occurrence of some character from a character class in regex?

Tags: java, regex, email

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\.]+\\sat\\s[\\w\\.]+");
```

Will match the following three lines from a web page:

```
dave.andersen at gmail.com
appear at SOSP
staring at now
```

However, I only want the first line to be matched. Is there a way to specify that there be at least one `dot` on both sides of `at`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea using "+" to indicate at least one, but using "[\w\.]+" matches any string of word characters or periods.

This will match things like "foo.bar at foo.bar" or "foo....bar at foo..bar":

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\.+\\w+\\sat\\s\\w+\\.+\\w+");
```

This will match things like "foo.bar at foo.bar" or "foo.bar.bar at foo.foo.bar":

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\.[\\w\\.]+\\sat\\s\\w+\\.[\\w\\.]+"
```

The difference between "\w+\.+\w+" and "[\w\.]+" is that the first form will match at least one word character followed by at least one period followed by at least one word character whereas the second form will match any mix up of word characters and periods.

Answer (score 1):

```
\w+\.\w+\s+at\s+\w+\.\w+
```

matches

> dave.andersen at gmail.com

but not:

> appear at SOSP

or:

> staring at now

**EDIT:**

```
\w+\.[\w\.]+\s+at\s+\w+\.[\w\.]+
```

matches `data.anderson at gmail.com` and `my.fair.lady at gmail.com`

Comment: I mean at least one occurrence rather than exactly one :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this

```
\w+\.\w+\sat\s\w+\.\w+
```

This will ensure that the "." appears between the words.

Here is the redefined version to match exactly one dot before and after "at"

you can replace it with

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\sat\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Comment: But it might have more than one dot :)